# How to declare a getProperty function in Typescript correctly?

Tags: typescript

I tried to declare a `prop(propName, obj)` function, but the type of returnValue have some inconsistencies.

I found a declaration on TS offical website which could infer the type of returnValue correctly, but a valid `name` parameter must be passed in function, and I prefer to infer the type `U` dynamicly.

```js
declare function getProperty<T, U extends keyof T>(name: U, obj: T): T[U];
```

### Code

```js
type PropOfObj<T, U> = U extends (keyof T) ? T[U] : unknown;
declare function prop<T, U>(propName: U, obj: T): PropOfObj<T, U>;

const n1 = prop('name', { name: 'David' }); // n1: unknown but expected string !!
const n2 = prop('name' as 'name', { name: 'David' }); // n2: string
const n3 = prop('name', { [Symbol('name')]: 'David' }); // n3: string

// 
const obj = { name: 'David' };
const key = 'name';

type T = typeof obj; // { name: string }
type U = typeof key; // "name"
type Extended = U extends keyof T ? T[U] : unknown; // string - which is expected and correct !!!
```

[Checkout on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=98#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAeQGbIEYCsA8AVAGigFUA+KAXhKggA9gIA7AEwGcoAKAawhAVSh4AlFAD8ggNrEAulABcUAK6MujBAHdGAbgBQzCAGMANgEM40VMoPAAlgkZQwiMPiJkOTpADkTAWwgKxEQI2ArCCvBIaJi4hCSkujoG9qzAUIwAjJSOzhwA5Ix+EHlEAN7pRQp5ACImAG42zHlQAL5CWlAA9J3pGQrKqhoOGIppdJDWEMxQqXA2jADmUACEy0kpaYwATNmeYPmF-s0m7AVFJVDlhwFQNfWNzW0d3elbCrPzC+uMqekAzLtcmcjmUoBIAMogXwYBBGA7nITSKq1BpNVrtLo9Rh-d7AOaLHQ6F7fX4hLDZK6VW4oh6tXTJH5pHggbLA4qJUCQQTZTkQfhQMnPHqU-y4-FLFo6XnUKi8-nMoVQABE1yVUvA0AAovQmPpplRiDQdSx2Mz+XgxJIZPIlCo1JpFR9FlAALRQdQACxsBg9UBs7HGhgY0xMLCgyTg5msK1WQA)

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain `U` as `U extends string`.

```
type PropOfObj<T, U extends string> = U extends keyof T ? T[U] : unknown;
declare function prop<T, U extends string>(propName: U, obj: T): PropOfObj<T, U>;
```

But to be honest, I'm not 100% sure why. My hunch is that something is widening the `U` type from `'name'` to `string`, and then `string extends keyof T ? T[string] : unknown` would take the false branch.

By constraining `U` to be at least be a string, that `U` seems to be inferred as `'name'` instead, and everything else works as it should.

This is also good because you probably don't want just any value to be passed in a prop. `prop(false, { name: 'David' })` *should* be a type error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAeQGbIEYCsA8AVAGigFUoIAPYCAOwBMBnKe4OAS2oHMA+KAXhLKUaDKAGsIIBKih4oAfhkBtYgF0oALigBXaqOoIA7tQDcAKFoQAxgBsAhnGiodl4KwTUoYRGHxFSFKjpGZjZOLgAKLyQAOVsAWwhNYiIEbE08AEpNeCQ0TFxCEi4zU0t3ZihqAEY+T29wgHJqeIgGogBvSpbNBoARWwA3VloGqABfDOMoAHppyqrNEPYOKHDUVnIIWgzS8uBKgCZaqLBG5oTR20YmlraoTvPEqD7B4dGJqdnDxZZl3eoKtQAMzHeo3C4dKCKADKIDiGAQ1jOtwyKh6-SGI3Gkxmc2BP1CHFMpi+-wqqSwtQe3WeGLe4zMZQB+3EIFq4NaJVAkBktW5ECkUApnzm1ISBOW41M-IE-H5gtZIqgACJHsrpeBoABRIR0La1fy6kSswWyBR4ZRqTQ6PSGEy4pi-ThQAC0UAMAAtWJYPVBWIwKJAXPrbHQoGU4A4XFAAIRxoA)

---

All that said, I want to say that I don't think you've improved upon the original:

```
declare function getProperty<T, U extends keyof T>(name: U, obj: T): T[U];
```

What you have instead is more code, with more cryptic types, and less type safety (since the argument could be anything instead of being constrained to the object's keys).

> "I prefer to infer the type U dynamicly."

That's happening in this original implementation from the T website, too. No point making it more complicated than it needs to be.